# Django: Adding files to a form gives multiple argument error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

Hi I have a Django project working perfectly fine. Now I need to add a field to it to upload documents.
However after adding the file stuffs, Django gives errors. Unable to solve it even after whole day Googling.

**Models.py**

```
class salesman(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    company=models.ForeignKey(Organisation,related_name='salesmancomp')
    salesman_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    salesman_address=models.CharField(max_length=750,null=True,blank=True)
    salesman_PAN=models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    salesman_commission_rate=models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    attachment = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together=(('company','salesman_name'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.salesman_name
```

**forms.py**

```
class salesmanform(forms.ModelForm): 
    def __init__(self,user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(salesmanform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model=salesman
        fields=('salesman_name','salesman_PAN','salesman_commission_rate','salesman_address','attachment',)
        widgets = {
            'salesman_address': forms.Textarea
        }  
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data=self.cleaned_data
        salesman_name=cleaned_data['salesman_name']
        pk=self.instance.pk
        insert = pk ==None
        if insert:
            try:
                salesman.objects.get(salesman_name=salesman_name,company=self.request.user.company.entity)
            except salesman.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Salesman already exist.")  
        else:
            pass       
        return cleaned_data
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def salesmancreate(request):

        action="Salesman Creation"
        if request.method == 'POST':
            rec_form=salesmanform(request.FILES,request=request,user=request.user,data=request.POST)
            if rec_form.is_valid():
                new_rec = rec_form.save(commit=False)
                new_rec.user = request.user
                new_rec.company=request.user.company.entity
                new_rec.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('salesmancreate'),{'section':'added'},messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,'Salesman added Succesfully'))
        else:
            rec_form=salesmanform(request=request,user=request.user)
        receivablescreated=salesman.objects.filter(company=request.user.company.entity).order_by('-id')
        return render(request,'account/salesman.html',{'rec_form':rec_form,'receivablescreated':receivablescreated,'action':action})
```

**My Template**

```
<form action="." method="post">

    <div class="form-group">

        {{ rec_form.salesman_name|attr:"class:form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Salesman Name"}}
    </div>

        <div class="input-group margin-b-20">

        {{ rec_form.salesman_commission_rate|attr:"class:form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Commission Perentage" }}
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-percent"></i></span>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">

        {{ rec_form.salesman_PAN|attr:"class:form-control"|attr:"placeholder:PAN of Salesman" }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        {{ rec_form.salesman_address|attr:"class:form-control"|attr:"style:height: 83px;"|attr:"placeholder:Address of Salesman" }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        {{ rec_form.attachment|attr:"class:form-control"|attr:"style:height: 83px;"|attr:"placeholder:Address of Salesman" }}
    </div>


    <div class="form-group clearfix">                                               
        <div class="pull-right">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success rounded">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Error Logs**:

```
TypeError at /salesmancreate/

__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/salesmancreate/
Django Version:     1.10
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'

Exception Location:     /Users/pulkitsharma/Documents/workspace/tiktant/invoice/views.py in salesmancreate, line 422
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.10
Python Path:    

['/Users/pulkitsharma/Documents/workspace/tiktant',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 3 Nov 2016 06:45:34 +0000

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/salesmancreate/

Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('invoice',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'widget_tweaks')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



    Traceback:

    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
      39.             response = get_response(request)

    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
      249.             response = self._get_response(request)

    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/pulkitsharma/Documents/workspace/tiktant/invoice/views.py" in salesmancreate
      422.             rec_form=salesmanform(request.FILES,request=request,user=request.user,data=request.POST)

    Exception Type: TypeError at /salesmancreate/
    Exception Value: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You override the `__init__` method so that the first argument is `user` but you pass `request.FILES` instead. Change the line:

```
rec_form=salesmanform(request.FILES,request=request,user=request.user,data=request.POST)
```

to

```
rec_form = salesmanform(user=request.user, data=request.POST,
                        files=request.FILES, request=request)
```

As a rule of thumb, try not to mix named and positional arguments, especially when you change the class constructor signature. Also consider changing your form name to `SalesmanForm` to be more compliant with [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) class naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you now form is working but file is not uploaded. I mean my attachment is not saved and also in database the attachment field is blank.

Comment: That's because you omitted `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` tag in the template. Please see [binding uploaded files to a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files) for details.

Comment: Made my day. Thanks a lot. Now how do i download this file when i edit the form? There is a link to attachment but when clicked, it gives URL error.

Comment: This is a new question which is difficult to answer in comments. Please post a new question with the details of the new error. Also post the contents of your `settings.py` relevant to `MEDIA` settings in that new question.

Comment: Need 90 minutes break it seems. SO policy. Will post and update question link here.

Comment: The link to new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396738/django-downloading-uploaded-files