# Django: Downloading uploaded files

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

I have form details in this question [Django: Adding files to a form gives multiple argument error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395455/django-adding-files-to-a-form-gives-multiple-argument-error)

How to download the uploaded file. When i go to edit view of the form, i can see uploaded file url, but its not downloading.
What setting to be changed for development and production mode?

Error upon clicking link:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/Certificate.docx

Using the URLconf defined in tiktant.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^ ^$ [name='home']
    ^ ^login/$ [name='login']
    ^ ^logout/$ [name='logout']
    ^ ^logout_then_login/$ [name='logout_then_login']
    ^ ^dashboard/$ [name='dashboard'] 
The current URL, media/Certificate.docx, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The media url is not showing in the root urls.py file. You need to add the below code in the urls.py file to enable the same.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Note: Please don't forget to add the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings.py file. For downloading a file, you need to write some more code.

Comment: This is working. Do i have to make any changes when i launch it, I mean same things will work for production mode too? I can download the file.

Comment: Can mark it solved, but second question is pending. Will there be any changes in production mode? With debug=False?

Comment: @PulkitSharma You have to run **python manage.py collectstatic** in order to load all the css, js and media files in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you added the following lines in your project
settings.py

```
import os 
def root(x):
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..',x)
MEDIA_ROOT = root('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    '-----------------------'
    'django.core.context_processors.media',

)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += patterns('',url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),

)
```